# trying to change admin password for openshift 3.11 cluster

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I have set up an openshift 3.11 cluster and want to change the admin password.  Below are the steps I have run.  The final command to my understanding is supposed to apply the change but it prompts me to set the password again which I think is the problem.

ssh to cluster as root then I ran these commands:

`htpasswd -c -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd ocadmin NEWPASSWORD`

`htpasswd -v /etc/origin/master/htpasswd ocadmin`
The new password verified correctly

`htpasswd /etc/origin/master/htpasswd ocadmin`
This just prompted me to edit the password again.  It returns a result stating the password is updating but nothing changes

Answer (score -1):

Issue is I have multiple master nodes in my cluster.  After updating the file and copying it to each of the master nodes it worked:

Final process is:

ssh to master00 node

`htpasswd -c -b /etc/origin/master/htpasswd ocadmin NEWPASSWORD`

`scp /etc/origin/master/htpasswd clusternamemaster-01:/etc/origin/master/htpasswd`

`scp /etc/origin/master/htpasswd clusternamemaster-02:/etc/origin/master/htpasswd`

etc